# Echo output to file with input string bigger than windows command length limit

Tags: echo, gnu-make

I need a list of all object file names with path written to a text file. I am not able to use the file function of GNU make since it is V3.79 . This list becomes really huge as it is a big project and therefore I get 'make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect' error, as it crosses the 32K windows command line length limit.

The original problem was that I need to pass the list of objects as a parameter to an archiver.exe to create a library, which also produced the e=87 issue. It's almost same as the problem listed [here](http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/archiving-error-make-e-87-The-parameter-is-incorrect-td13458.html). That's when I decided to put this list to a text file and pass the file as parameter to archiver.exe. But I am stranded because creating the file itself is producing the same error. Following is what I tried:

```
MY_OBJECTS = $(shell $(FIND) $(MY_OBJPATH) -name '*.o')
MY_OBJECTSLIST = objlist.txt
all:
     @echo $(MY_OBJECTS) > $(MY_OBJECTSLIST)
```

I need a solution to somehow put the entire objects list to the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#File-Function) function.

```
all:
     $(file > $(MY_OBJECTSLIST) $(MY_OBJECTS))
```

Note that the search for `MY_OBJECTS` files happens as soon as `MY_OBJECTS` is evaluated, regardless if you are running a relevant target or not. In this case, you can offload the work from make to shell in the actual target. the output of `find` is a stream and doesn't have the limitation of shell command line length.

Plus, `objlist.txt` is a file! That's what `make` does the best - builds a file exactly when it's needed, no sooner, no earlier.

```
all: objlist.txt
     @echo $(MY_OBJECTS) > $(MY_OBJECTSLIST)

objlist.txt: <should better depend on the condition that all the *.o files are already built>
     $(FIND) $(MY_OBJPATH) -name '*.o' > objlist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate file?

```
MY_OBJECTS = $(shell $(FIND) $(MY_OBJPATH) -name '*.o' | tee objects.txt)
MY_OBJECTSLIST = objlist.txt
all:
    cp objects.txt ${MY_OBJECTSLIST}
```

Many opportunities for optimisation here of course.